# Google Fit does not give step count

Tags: android, google-fit

I am trying to get step count from google fit inside an Android app. App successfully gets called to `onConnected()` after selecting the google account. I have configured the *Google API Console* with correct SHA1 finger print and package name too. So there cannot be any wrong with Console.

However it never gets hit to `onDataPoint()` [this used to work before].

I am pasting the code after `onConnected` here.

```
DataSourcesRequest dataSourceRequest = new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
        .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
        .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
        .build();

ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult> dataSourcesResultCallback = new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
        for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
            if (DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE.equals(dataSource.getDataType())) {

                registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE);

            }
        }
    }
};

Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mApiClient, dataSourceRequest)
        .setResultCallback(dataSourcesResultCallback);
```

and then

```
private void registerFitnessDataListener(DataSource dataSource, DataType dataType) {
Log.e("GoogleFit", "registerFitnessDataListener");
SensorRequest request = new SensorRequest.Builder()
    .setDataSource(dataSource)
    .setDataType(dataType)
    .setSamplingRate(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();


Fitness.SensorsApi.add(mApiClient, request, this)
    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                Log.e("GoogleFit", "SensorApi successfully added");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Can someone help me with the reason why it is not getting hit inside `onDataPoint()` method??

Comment: Found that my dataSourcesResultCallback returns with DataSourceResult{status=Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}, data Sets=[]}.  But it never goes into the  for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {}
for loop

Comment: Have you tried putting in Logs inside your `onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult)`? See if it actually gets there? Or check the count of `dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()`?

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. I solved it by using DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED when building the DataSourcesRequest.

Comment: You should [answer your own question and mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED when building the DataSourcesRequest. I think this happens as a result of my testing device which is Nexus 7 is having a software sensor rather than hardware sensor. As a result off that I cannto get results for TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA.